# MuseScore output to MIDI keyboard

Tags: midi, windows, keyboard

My 10 year old son is learning to play the piano and has a [Yamaha PSR-E213](http://uk.yamaha.com/en/products/musical-instruments/keyboards/digitalkeyboards/portable_keyboards/psr-e213/)

We also have a laptop and a [Midisport 2x2](http://www.m-audio.com/products/en_us/MIDISPORT2x2.html) USB interface and he wants to start using them together.

We have successfully connected [MuseScore](http://musescore.org/) to the keyboard and he is able to see his playing on the keyboard appearing on the laptop.

However, we cannot figure out how to get the playback from MuseScore to sound through the keyboard's speakers.

MIDI OUT on the keyboard is connected to IN-A on the 2x2 and MIDI IN on the keyboard is connected to OUT-A on the 2x2. Only the IN-A LED is lit on the 2x2.

Is this possible?

Comment: You just need to change your MIDI output device.  What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 - I've added a tag

Answer (score 2):

MuseScore does not support direct output to a MIDI device.
(I think that is because it is designed to work on different operating systems where MIDI implementations are totally different)

**However**, it can use the JACK software to provide this function.
For an explanation, see [the following entry on the MuseScore forums](http://musescore.org/en/node/3267)

For additional clarification, please post a question on the MuseScore forums and someone much more knowledgeable than me will help with any problem you have with this.
Good luck.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I was looking for. I'll give this a go tonight...